# How to request Http request and response in json

Tags: json, http, windows-phone-7

One major question is I can't simply use existed json library to put into my windows phone 7 applications.Is there any existed json library for wp7?

Another is how to request http and get response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the Hammock Rest library on Codeplex alongside the excellent NewtonSoft JSON.NET library - also on codeplex.